# Как в переменную засунуть видео

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть код js, и туда нужно запихнуть вместо цветов видео. Как это сделать? отправьте пожалуйста код.

```
onclick='switchBg();'

var bgar = ['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f'], curBg = 0;
function switchBg(){ 
    document.body.style.background = bgar[++curBg % bgar.length];
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Ну воспользуйтесь `innerHTML` вставьте видео.

Comment: Я тоже ничего не понял, но как минимум https://html5book.ru/html5-video/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужно было что-то такое.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let button = document.querySelector('button');

let video = `<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" autoplay muted></video>`;

button.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  container.innerHTML = video;
})
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```